# Apache trying to access directory that doesn't match symlink

Tags: symbolic-link, apache-http-server

I've got a symlink like so:

```
/home/site1/public_html/site2
```

whereby site2_symlink was set up like this:

```
ln -s /home/site2/public_html/ site2
```

and I have follow symlinks turned on in my Virtual Hosts entry:

```
<Directory / >
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

but I get a 404 and the apache error_log says:

```
File does not exist: /home/public_html/site2
```

EDIT change symlink name but makes no difference to outcome

Answer (score 1):

Your symlink is called `site2_symlink` and apache is looking for `site2`. Renaming the symlink would probably solve it if everything else is ok.

Apache is looking for `/home/public_html/site2` acording to the log. Not `/home/site1/public_html/site2`?

Comment: But apache is looking for /home/public_html/site2 not /home/site2/public_html I've changed the symlink names and the problem still exists

Comment: Then the problem is in your DocumentRoot I suppose or in an alias. Can you post the whole apache config file?

Comment: Maybe not necessary to post the config, only checking if DocumentRoot is set to `/home/site1/public_html` (where the symlink is located) would be suficient. You are using URL from site1 with `/site2` at the end to access, right? I suppose site1 is not working too if apache is not looking in the right directory.

Comment: That's a good point - I never thought to check that - actually site1 has nothing in it - it's a whacky setup for an SSL for 400+ sites because client refuses to pay for SSL per site for a contact form...